# Suggestion for Validate Model Error Message

Tags: mdriven

What I see

**Info**:

```
Model errors:
MVH201 Derivation expression specified for non-derived attribute (Issue.Job) [Issue.Job]
```

I'm wondering if this was intended to be
**MVH201** Derivation expression specified for non-derived attribute

```
("class.attribute") ["Derivation expression"]
```

Answer (score 0):

If you at first had the attribute as derived - and then in a subclass added an override for it (derivation expressions on the subclass) - but then made the original attribute persistent again (none derived) -> bam!

MDriven will warn you that the derivation expression in the subclass is there - but it has no effect.